# Вывод списка через array_splice, что не так сделал?

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? выводит заметки как попало. Нужно вывести сначала две заметки, затем еще 6 в разных оформлениях.

```html
<?php if($articles): ?>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="container cf">
    <div class="large b-row cf">
      <!-- Здесь выводится 2 первые заметки-->
      <?php $first_articles = array_splice($articles, 2); ?>
      <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
      <div class="column half b-col">
        <article>
          <a href="#"> </a>
          <h2 class="post-title"><a href="#"><?=$article->title;?></a></h2>
          <div class="cf listing-meta meta below"> <span class="meta-item author"><?=$article->title;?> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 3</a></span></div>
          <div class="excerpt">
            <p>
              <?=$article->description;?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <ul class="b-row posts-list thumb">
      <!-- снова перебираем массив но уже в нем будут удалены выведенные выше объекты -->
      <?php $last_articles = array_splice($articles, -6); ?>
      <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
      <li class="column half b-col">
        <article class="post cf">
          <a href="#"> </a>
          <div class="content">
            <a href="#"><?=$article->title;?></a>
            <div class="cf listing-meta below"> <time datetime="2017" class="meta-item">Jan 10, 2017</time></div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$last_articles = array_splice($articles,-6)` поместит в результат последние 6 элементов массива и одновременно удалит их из исходного

```
  <?php $last_articles = array_splice($articles,-6); ?>
  <!-- теперь в массиве только 2 эелмента -->
  <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
  ...
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <!-- теперь перебираем остальные 6 -->
  <?php foreach($last_articles as $article): ?>
```